# CASE inside a COALESCE

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, coalesce

I have two Redshift tables with timestamp values. One of them have local with some nulls and the other have GMT but no nulls. I also have a country column in table 2. 
I want to query the local time values, and use COALESCE with CASE depending on the country for the null values.
I have tried with

```
 CASE 
        WHEN (T1.local_time = '' OR T1.local_time=NULL) AND T2.country = 'UK'  THEN T2.gmt_time
        WHEN (T1.local_time = '' OR T1.local_time=NULL) AND T2.country = 'ES' DATEADD(hour, 1, T2.gmt_time)
        ...
 ELSE T2.gmt_time END AS final_time
```

but it was not capturing null values. COALESCE (NVL) allows me to capture NULL values but I am not sure where to place the case. I have tried:

```
COALESCE (T1.local_time, 
          CASE
            WHEN T2.country = 'UK' THEN DA
            WHEN T2.COUNTRY = 'SP' THEN DATEADD(hour, 1, T2.gmt_time)
            ...
          ELSE T2.gmt_time END AS local_time) 
AS time_final)
```

But I am receiving error. The query is quite big therefore I want to avoid temp tables. Any workaround?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't that be `... OR T1.local_time IS NULL`?

Comment: Thanks! That actually solved my first code therefore I do not need the COALESCE.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone struggling with this issue, to appropriately write a CASE statement within a COALESCE statement, the code should be revised as follows:

```
COALESCE (T1.local_time, 
          CASE
            WHEN T2.country = 'UK' THEN DA
            WHEN T2.COUNTRY = 'SP' THEN DATEADD(hour, 1, T2.gmt_time)
            ...
          ELSE T2.gmt_time END) AS time_final
```

Answer (score 0):

`Null` is not a value, it's the lack thereof. You can't evaluate it with the `=` operator (that checks that two values are equal), but have to use the `is` operator:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (T1.local_time = '' OR T1.local_time IS NULL) AND T2.country = 'UK'
        THEN T2.gmt_time
    WHEN (T1.local_time = '' OR T1.local_time IS NULL) AND T2.country = 'ES' 
        THEN DATEADD(hour, 1, T2.gmt_time)
        ...
   ELSE T2.gmt_time
END AS final_time
```

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE` will return the first value that isn't `NULL`.

In this case this would be the following.

```
CASE 
  WHEN (COALESCE(T1.local_time, '') = '') AND T2.country = 'UK' THEN T2.gmt_time
  WHEN (COALESCE(T1.local_time, '') = '') AND T2.country = 'ES' THEN DATEADD(hour, 1, T2.gmt_time)
    ...
ELSE T2.gmt_time END AS final_time
```

See also Redshifts documentation on [COALESCE/NVL Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to use coalesce here, you can just add the case when local_time is not null:

```
          CASE
            WHEN T1.local_time IS NOT NULL AND T1.local_time != '' THEN T1.local_time
            WHEN T2.country = 'UK' THEN DA
            WHEN T2.COUNTRY = 'SP' THEN DATEADD(hour, 1, T2.gmt_time)
            ...
          ELSE T2.gmt_time END AS local_time)
```